# Oledbconnection

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I'm trying to create a method that will allow me to simply pass an SQL Command to a database with ease. I keep running into this error for some reason though. [image: dberror]
The full string is this `Couldn't fetch the required data. Update unable to find TableMapping['tables'] or DataTable 'tables'.`

My Database method is this:

```
public void AddToDatabase(string strAccessSelect) 
{
    Connection();
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        myAccessConn.Open();

        OleDbCommand OleDbUpdateCommand = myAccessConn.CreateCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        myDataAdapter.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(strAccessSelect, myAccessConn);

        myDataAdapter.Update(myDataSet, "tables");
        myDataSet.AcceptChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = "Couldn't fetch the required data. " + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            myAccessConn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure i'm making some really stupid mistake, but I just can't seem to figure this out! I hope someone can help me, Thank You!

Comment: You're trying to delete something but you are using an `InsertCommand`.

Comment: @khlr Thank you, I didn't spot that! However, i'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you want to do but maybe

```html
  public void AddToDatabase(string strAccessSelect)
      {
         try
         {
            myAccess.Open();
            OleDbCommand OleDbUpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand(strAccessSelect, myAccess);
            OleDbUpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            error = "Couldn't fetch the required data. " + ex.Message;
         }
         finally
         {
            myAccessConn.Close();
         }
      }
```

Comment: @davehey My error changed to `Couldn't fetch the required data. Data type mismatch in criteria expression.` I'm not sure if your change worked, but it seems like this error is with my SQL Statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will help

for Delete
[http://csharp.net-informations.com/dataadapter/deletecommand-oledb.htm](http://Oledb%20Delete)

for Insert
[http://csharp.net-informations.com/dataadapter/insertcommand-oledb.htm](http://Oledb%20Insert)

Other links on above url also help you.

**I didn't test the code shown in above url.